# Should I use different AdMob Ad Units ID in different Activities?

Tags: android, android-activity, admob

Should I use the same Ad Unit ID for all the ads in my app or should I get one ID per Activity?

Comment: Facing same problem, thanks for an advance

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can use one Ad Unit ID for all banner ads within your app and a different Ad Unit ID for all interstitial ads within the same app.

Thus, if your app contains only banner ads, it can have only one Ad Unit ID. If your app contains banner and interstitial ads, it can have two Ad Unit IDs.

However, according to the official admob guide, YES! you can use one ID per activity:

> An Ad Unit ID is a unique identifier given to the places in your app where ads are displayed. If you have an app with two activities, for example, each displaying a banner, you need two ad units, each with its own ID.

For reporting sake, use different ad unit for each application. This helps you know how each application is performing in regards to eCPMs, requests and clicks. It will help you understand the market, adjust or improve your apps as needed.

It's not against the policy if that's what you want. ([Check this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/gNZ6xD0IXw8/x6axuJEmXK8J))

Comment: great answer. Thank you

Comment: why does google suggest to have one ad unit per ad on app? just for monitoring purposes? if an app has 20 ads it means 20 ad units and as they recommend you to use test ads during test and only set your official ad units on releases it creates the sake of always change 20 fields of unique ad units... makes no sense

Answer (score 45):

Actually, according to the [Admob for Android Guide](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start) , yes you should!

> An Ad Unit ID is a unique identifier given to the places in your app where ads are displayed. If you have an app with two activities, for example, each displaying a banner, you need two ad units, each with its own ID.

Comment: Agree with @Rushi. Also I searched the Admob help and couldn't find the above. Simple question. Oh well...

Answer (score 6):

I had the same concern and looked into the link Nana gave. 
This is [one of the messages](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/gNZ6xD0IXw8/ugHqvYDfx7EJ) that caught my eye:

> Hi Sonic,
>
> You're still *allowed* to do this, but we recommend against it, and if
>   you link an app then house ads might not work. We recommend creating a
>   different Ad Unit ID for every placement you have (which means you'll
>   probably have multiple per app).
>
> Hope this helps!
>
> Amy Quispe

IMHO, you should have a different ad unit for each BannerView you display.

Comment: So, if I have 3 ads in 3 different activities then I should have 3 different  Ad Unit ID? That was what I thought the first time, but finally I used the same for all of the ads.

Comment: I think you'll get the same results, but you won't be able to track which screen brought you more money.

Answer (score -1):

I think there are many theories about this issue
But my suggestion to use multi ads unit
Because admob Disterbute ads for every unit by equal
And if you have multi ads your probabilty to have ads will be bigger