# Should I make separate Ad Unit for every activity?

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I have total 30+ activities in my Android App. Should I create 30 ad units also? How can I track the performance of each activity? Do I need to create 30 separate ad units? Or can I track which activity generates most revenue? and which less? which has good CTR? which has less CTR? etc. details?

Comment: you should be able to use 1 AD Id for all activities, use firebase analytics to track which page is access more.. Creating separate Ad unit ids for each activity is allowed. Please see this link for answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25596191/should-i-use-different-admob-ad-units-id-in-different-activities