# Using AdUnit correctly in an Android app

Tags: android, interstitial, adbannerview, admob

I have an Android app, with around 25 activities.

According to AdMob Guidelines, we should only have one AdUnit for one activity, right?

So, how many AdUnits, we can add in an Android app for Banner and Interstitial Ads?

Is their any limit for number of AdUnits in an Android app?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25596191/should-i-use-different-admob-ad-units-id-in-different-activities may help you

Comment: Thanks @CLIFFORDPY. I checked that link before. It isn't giving a perfect answer. It isn't answering about the limit of AdUnits in an Android app.

Comment: I think for all your activity just one Ad Unit needed for banner and one AdUnit for interstitial .

Comment: Are you sure about it? I have heard both the points, 1) One AdUnit, 2) Seperate AdUnits

Comment: @AmanChawla From where you get the knoweldge of  "we should only have one AdUnit for one activity"

Comment: @CLIFFORDPY I saw it as an answer on many StackOverflow questions related to AdUnits. Have you worked on using a single AdUnit for all activities?

Comment: @AmanChawla ,Yes i used single ad-units for multiple activities

Comment: I just answered my question below.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Google AdMob Guidelines,](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start)

> An ad unit ID is a unique identifier given to the places in your app where ads are displayed. Create an ad unit for each activity your app will perform. **If you have an app with two activities, for example, each displaying a banner, you need two ad units, each with its own ID**. AdMob ad unit IDs have the form ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/NNNNNNNNNN.

I guess this answers the question.