# Is there any way to pull earning from a specific page by adsense?

Tags: adsense, adsense-api

I am trying to find out a way to get revenue generated by a page of my website.

For example my website have 10 pages(a,b,c,....) and they all have ads placed on them.

I need to calculate revenue generated by page a,b,c and so on .

Like :

```
Page a = 10$
Page b = 12.5$
```

Answer (score 1):

You can link adsense with google analytics to get detailed revenue info.

Answer (score 0):

Apply ads on each page with different Ids.

Comment: My application will have dynamic pages and it will have more than 2000 pages. This is not a solution

Answer (score -1):

There is one SEO tool, if you know the page impressions, CTR and Cost per click, you can easily calculate it - [Google Adsense Calculator](http://tools.seochat.com/tools/google-adsense-calculator/)

This answer is focused on [monetizing through Ad-Mob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25596191/should-i-use-different-admob-ad-units-id-in-different-activities).

For further reading [google group forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/gNZ6xD0IXw8/x6axuJEmXK8J)

Comment: not the correct solution. My application will have more than 2k pages i cannot create ad units per page. and i need exact revenue generated per page not the estimated one

Comment: The answer was based on your question for 10 pages. If you give a hypothetical scenario of 2k pages, who has the time to look and calculate the "exact revenue generated per page" that too, "dynamic pages". I would suggest that you join google ad-sense forums. Also, to better understand can we have the screenshots to your exact scenario...

Comment: i have time and need to calculate

Comment: Not the answer to specific question. He is not asking to find avg each page is making but specific value.